# How export logs from AWS Lambda to S3 bucket without CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How I can send or export logs from my AWS Lambda function to S3 without using by CloudWatch?

Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can stop your cloudwatch log ingesting from function and send the log to another destination.
Please check- [Disabling logging to CloudWatch Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-aws-lambda-extensions-to-send-logs-to-custom-destinations/#:%7E:text=Disabling%20logging%20to%20CloudWatch%20Logs)

Answer (score 0):

This AWS Sample shows you have to use a [Lambda extension to send logs to S3](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-extensions/tree/main/s3-logs-extension-demo-zip-archive). But there is currently no way to stop logs from going to CloudWatch.

Comment: Can you locate straight to Loki?

Comment: Can you please provide more context? Is this another question?

Comment: My question is do I have another way to take Lambda logs and transfer them to Loki without using cloud watch. At the end of my goal I move Lambda logs to Graphena Loki

Comment: The same method could be used to send logs anywhere. The example implementation is to S3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930281/python-parse-str-to-json-send-to-loki